# Optional Obj not rendering hands on table

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Currently I am using handsontably 6.2.2 and I am trying to load a data set I get from a database but it will not render if I have an included table in the query that may or may not be there. I have tried to use custom rendering but it errors out before those are called and the only function that will log anything before erroring out is the beforeGetCellMeta but I cannot successfully change the value in this function. I may be doing that part wrong.

Here is my obj I am passing into Handsontable

```
data: [
   {id: 1, name: "Test Name", includedTable: null},
   {id: 2, name: Test Name 2", includedTable: {
      id: 1, 
      name: "IncludedTableRowName"
    }},
];
```

Below is the handsontable I am calling.

```
hot1 = new Handsontable(container, {
            data: data,
            colHeaders: ['id', 'Name', 'Table Row Name'],
            columns: [
                {data: 'id'},
                {data: 'name'},
                {data: 'includedTable.name'}
            ]
        });
```

All I get is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null` on the includedTable.name. I get that it is undefined in the first but shouldnt it just render null in that case? If not I need help getting this to work with a customer render function or something else because I have tried custom renders, custom types, all the function within handsontable before to get the values to work and nothing has let me do this.

Comment: you must not have to define `includedTable: null` in case of null value so now your ```data: [
   {id: 1, name: "Test Name"},
   {id: 2, name: "Test Name 2", includedTable: {
      id: 1, 
      name: "IncludedTableRowName"
    }},
];```

Comment: What if I dont have a choice on the api return though?

Comment: then manipulate that object before you pass it to `Handsontable` table, let me know if that work for you, I can write a full code for the same.

Comment: Thank you that did work, I was hoping for a custom render solution or object type solution but it looks like I have to modify the data before being passed into the handsontable.